# TypeORM return plain object

Tags: javascript, database, orm, sequelize.js, typeorm

How do I return a plain JavaScript object from TypeORM Repository functions like `find`, `create`, `update` or `delete`?

```js
const user = User.findOne({ where: { id: 1 } });
```

Actual:

```
User | undefined

{
  User: {
    id: 1
  }
}
```

Instead I would like to receive a plain object independent from any library / framework

Expected:

```js
{
  id: 1
}
```

This way it would be easier to be framework independent and your repository calls could be interchangeable at any point of time without rewriting the entire application and not to depend on third party scripts that heavily.

[Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#instance-method-get) for example has an option `{ plain: true }`

Answer (score 4):

You can easily use the class-transformer library to produce plain objects from entity instances:

https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer

```
const user = repository.findOne({ where: { id: 1 } });
const plain = classToPlain(user);
```

Another way is to use queryBuilder API and returns raw results from the database

```
const rawResult = repository.createQueryBuilder("user")
    .select("user")
    .where("user.id = :id", {id: 1})
    .getRawOne();
```

The point is why would you want to do so? Entity is first citizen in TypeOrm so you want that any change on its structure should generate compile errors if something is not back compatible. Using plain objects would hide contract changes, and you would discover errors only at runtime, not sure if it is an optimal way to work with TypeOrm to my mind.

Comment: Sometimes we just want plain data without the functions and wrappers, to pass to UI, to pass outside world... Transformation and extraction are OK but they would make the source code growing ugly

Comment: today, since classToPlain() function is deprecated, you should use instanceToPlain() function instead of it.